# How to output Select-String text to a file without the line break?

Tags: powershell

This is my code:

```
$ccToSearch =@('"1008-0000108812"', "1008-0000105138", "1008-0000120485")

$ccToSearch =  $ccToSearch -split ',' | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() }

$results5 = Select-String -Path "C:\Logs\tm1s202205*.log" -Pattern $ccToSearch 

$results5 | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Users\User\Desktop\log.txt"
```

and this is the result:

```
tm1s20220615160000.log:622:"","20220615152345","20220615152345","N","9.279340000000001e-003","0","OPEX","1008-0000108812","1008-0000750055","5760012285","Input","5555","2022","Cur
rent Cycle","Other","Direct Input","Value in Millions",""
tm1s20220615160000.log:623:"","20220615152345","20220615152345","N","1.975e-002","0","OPEX","1008-0000108812","1008-0000750055","5760012202","Input","5555","2022","Current 
Cycle","Other","Direct Input","Value in Millions",""
```

I want each line in a separate line but without the line break, like this:

```
tm1s20220615160000.log:622:"","20220615152345","20220615152345","N","9.279340000000001e-003","0","OPEX","1008-0000108812","1008-0000750055","5760012285","Input","5555","2022","Current Cycle","Other","Direct Input","Value in Millions",""
tm1s20220615160000.log:623:"","20220615152345","20220615152345","N","1.975e-002","0","OPEX","1008-0000108812","1008-0000750055","5760012202","Input","5555","2022","Current Cycle","Other","Direct Input","Value in Millions",""
```

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: export it as Csv instead of plain text, `Select-String` outputs actual objects not plain text

Comment: Are you able to share at least a section of the log file, so anyone on here can test a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using Export-Csv instead of Out-File worked.

```
$results5 | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\User\Desktop\log5.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```